# How to parse python multiple line string by triple quotes """...""" with lex/flex?

Tags: python, c++, flex-lexer, lex

I want to parse python multiple line strings `"""string"""` with lex/flex.

Here's part of my flex:

```
%x MULTISTR

%{
#include <cstdio>
%}

%%

"\"\"\""                { BEGIN MULTISTR; }
<MULTISTR>"\"\"\""      { BEGIN INITIAL; }
<MULTISTR>([^*]|\n)+|.  { yylval.str = strdup(yytext, yyleng); return T_MULTISTR; }
<MULTISTR><<EOF>>       { std::fprintf(stderr, "error! unterminated multiple line string!\n"); }
%%
```

But when I test it, I got error message:

```
error! unterminated multiple line string!
```

Please help me fix this token parsing!

Comment: First of all please try to create a [mcve] to show us, including how you call the lexer. Also please show us the actual input (copy-pasted as text) you use.

Comment: Please, note that `([^*]|\n)+|.` is able to match the longer sequence compared to `"\"\"\""`.  You have to exclude the triple quotes from that somehow.

Comment: To show an example: `"\""("\\".|[^\\"])*"\""` is (my) flex pattern to match C string literals, including the handling of nested double quotes prefixed with backslash.

Comment: @Scheff, thanks, it solve my problem!